# not get the cntl to application

Tags: linux-kernel

I am a linux device driver programmer.

Recentely i write driver for sniffer hardware.

This sniffer hardware will continously read data from the bus line.

I have an interrupt handler in my driver to notify the received data.

I am used dma address mapping for store the data.

h/w use pyhsical address, driver use vitual address.

my problem, Always interrupt handler received data interrupt to receiver the data.

My application unable to get cntl to get the data from the driver.

Interrupt handler not give cntl to application side. Bcoz of continuos not stopping interrupt.

What can i do? please help me.

Thanks
Sundar

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need figure out how to speed up your interrupt handler.

Answer (score 0):

Use NAPI like method - when you get the interrupt that notifies you on existing data, you:

1. Disable Rx interrupt.
2. Start/wake up  a kernel thread / work queue to start harvesting the data from the device. Keep doing that until you have harvested all data in the ring buffer. Make sure to yield let application run from time to time (e.g. sleep for X ms every 1000 packets).
3. Only when you have finished harvesting all incoming data, kill/ put to sleep the kernel thread / work queue and re-enable Rx interrupts.